# Unencrypted SHA2 Stored Procedure text in MySQL showing in the General log for MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

We've implemented a stored procedure in MySQL 5.6 that checks a user login using the following;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CheckLogin`(iUserId INTEGER, sPassword varchar(25))
BEGIN
    SELECT UserId FROM UserTable
    WHERE Password = SHA2(sPassword,256)
    And UserId = iUserId;
END
```

The stored procedure works fine, by returning the UserId if the password is matched.

At the moment we have General MySQL Logging enabled, and I noticed that the users password that they entered is in plain text and visible in the Log File.

With this security risk in mind, is it better to move the SHA2 functionality to within my actual ASP.NET application and hash the password using C# ?

The other option is that I just don't enable MySQL general logging.

Comment: It would be better if applications hashed the entered password and passed that to the sproc.  This minimizes the network transports that the password passes through as well as keeping it out of memory/logs on the database server.

Comment: Maybe this suggested link can help provide some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983381/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-password-in-mysql-general-slow-query-logs