# Hash password with triggers using bcrypt

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to hash password using triggers?

I was thinking something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `hash_password`
    AFTER INSERT ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE users SET password = HASH(NEW.password)
    END
```

But how do I make it encrypted with bcrypt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use \`bcrypt\` algorithm within \`encrypt\` function in MySQL for verifying password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295778/how-to-use-bcrypt-algorithm-within-encrypt-function-in-mysql-for-verifying-p)

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords. You *must* hash them. Don't take this matter lightly. It has ***major*** legal significance.

Comment: @EJP It was just a mis-understanding, I really meant hash, as I was asking about bcrypt.