# database column encryption in spring

Tags: java, spring, authentication, encryption

I create a user manually via db(mysql). Now I want to encrypt the password for this user.How do I do this?
Currently this is how I have acheived it.

```
1. Create a user in db with cleartext password
2. in my code while server startup, I check if password is cleartext then i encrypt it using bcrypt.
3. in spring-security.xml i have added bcrypt bean to decrypt it.
```

But using this approach I have to restart the server each time I add a new user.
Any other way to do this?
Using spring 4

Comment: Well that's easy. Remove step 2 completely, then replace step 1 with "Create user in db with bcrypted password".

Comment: Please follow the link for bcrypt algo in mysql. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295778/how-to-use-bcrypt-algorithm-within-encrypt-function-in-mysql-for-verifying-p