# How to set PHP compatible password directly in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I need to assign password to some user directly in database, what is the correct way to  a assign a value compatible with  `password_hash(A_DB_COLUMN, ANY_POSSIBLE_ALGORITHM)` method using only MySQL features?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html

Comment: I guess the answer is you cannot, as [seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20296312).. Here is a way you can [strictly with php](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32556010)