# Using phpMyAdmin to update user passwords encrypted with PASSWORD_BCRYPT

Tags: php, mysql

Solved:  See @RiggsFolly answer below for adequate work around.

Goal:  I want to update user passwords using phpMyAdmin that have been stored using the password_hash() with PASSWORD_BCRYPT.

I am working on a web DB where the user passwords are set using php code such as:

```
$newPWHash = password_hash($newPW, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

and then written into the database using:

```
$sql = "update employees set pw_hash = :newpwhash where employee_id = :id";
```

That part is fine, and I get how that is working.  However, now I am trying to go back in an change user passwords for a number of accounts I created, and I would prefer to do it using phpMyAdmin's SQL window.  I have tried:

```
UPDATE  `table` SET  `pw_hash` = PASSWORD('test') WHERE `email_address` =  'myemail@email.com'
```

However, this doesn't seem to be generating the same password.  All the other passwords have the $2$y structure, and the ones generated by the above are not.

How to get this to work?

Comment: `PASSWORD('test')` !== `password_hash('test', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)`

Comment: Thats right its not the same. Write a User password change script. You will need one anyway

Comment: I have a user reset function that works, but it mails out the password to the user - since these are dummy accounts I basically just want to set a bunch of passwords manually - hence wanting to do it with PhPmyAdmin

Comment: @Federkun is there to use {PASSWORD('test')} in a way that would make it work in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use \`bcrypt\` algorithm within \`encrypt\` function in MySQL for verifying password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295778/how-to-use-bcrypt-algorithm-within-encrypt-function-in-mysql-for-verifying-p)

Comment: My Workaround: Create a new acc using normal PHP method using a password you like. Then copy paste this HASHED password into which ever accounts you want to mess with using a simple UPDATE query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - that works.  Thanks for helping come up with a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to highlight that there is an answer for this now:
My Workaround: Create a new acc using normal PHP method using a password you like. Then copy paste this HASHED password into which ever accounts you want to mess with using a simple UPDATE query. – RiggsFolly Dec 11 '16 at 10:51