# How to know which algorithm has been used to encrypt existing passwords in a table

Tags: mysql, hash, password-encryption

In here i want to add a record to a Mysql `users` table manually. There is a field called `encrypted_password` but i dont know the encryption algorithm that has been used. When Im trying to add a record manually but it didnt work when im authenticating.

Sample of existing user record password hash :

```
encrypted_password: $2a$12$ibqhezRBPsy022fhMqGXBOtT749jR4QMwBULS4o1x9NMycPbftPwa
```

The query i tried to insert for the new record.

```
INSERT INTO users(status,classification,encrypted_password,created_at,updated_at) values(1,1,MD5('test1234$'), NOW(), NOW());
```

The hash format of the record I inserted :

```
encrypted_password: b46cfe70ccedca93ed4f06f5e5901fea
```

How can i have a workaround this and add an encrypted password in correct hash format?

Comment: It's bcrypt encryption. Encryption method and salt is already in password: `$2a$` with cost of `12`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt

Comment: Encrypt password in back-end, not in database. Does this answer your question? [How to use \`bcrypt\` algorithm within \`encrypt\` function in MySQL for verifying password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295778/how-to-use-bcrypt-algorithm-within-encrypt-function-in-mysql-for-verifying-p)

Comment: This is not [tag:password-encryption], and nor should be it. It is password *hashing*. See the tag description for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, we can follow the below steps.

1. Identify the password hashing algorithm using an online hash analyzer.
2. Based on that hashing algorithm generate a new hash using an online hash generator.
3. Update the table record entry with that hash.
4. Now login should be successful with the plain text that has been used for the hash generation.

Comment: Please do not post answers that contain only links to other external ressources